# How to see originating folders for search results with Windows Search 4 in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-search

With Window Search nicely integrated into Outlook 2010, I can search for a phrase and get a list of search results. But how do I display the source folder for each item in the results list? Surely this capability must exist?! I assume I am just missing an obvious setting somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on the heading then choose View Settings then Columns you can customise which columns appear. On my Outlook, which I don't remember changing from the default, the last column is "In Folder", but it doesn't appear. If I move it to the top of the list then it appears instead of the email subject. If you increase the maximum number of lines in compact view, from that Columns dialog, you get the email subject back again.

Alternatively if you right click on the heading you can group things by folder.

Comment: Perfect; both suggestions are helpful to me! One other trick I found while looking at your first tip: in the skinny search column, I also observed that In Folder does not appear. But one can make it visible by just making the search column wider.

Comment: (for OutLook 2010) The "In Folder" header can be added by right clicking on existing headers, selecting "Field Chooser" and the selecting "All Mail fields" and dragging "In Folder" to the header bar.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have added the In Folder per instructions above, start your search,  once the data is populated, go to the extreme bottom of the page and click on "Try searching again in All Mail Items".  The "In Folder" column will then populate.